# Yii2 Checkbox Changes Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, yii2

I have a `GridView` displaying employee payslips, and beside each of their names are check boxes. Refer to the picture below:

[image]

As you can see, I also have a drop-down list. I set it in my jQuery to select the last child of the list which is my case, the *April 10, 2015 - April 16, 2015* option. On page load, I can see this page (photo above) with those check boxes. I had a problem with the check boxes since when I click the header check box, it should select all of the check boxes below it. But it's not. Now, when I tried selecting another option in the drop-down list, here's what I get:

[image]

The style of the check boxes changes. And now, when I check the header check box, it's already working, selecting every check boxes below.

Here's how I display the **drop-down list**:

```
echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'period',
    'data' => $period,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select period', 
        'id' => 'period',
        'style' => 'width: 400px; height: 34px;'
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'maximumInputLength' => 10,
    ],
]);
```

**GridView**:

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'employee']); ?>
<?php   
    echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'options' => ['class' => 'icheckbox_minimal',]

            ],
                'fname',
                'lname',
                'totalEarnings',
                'totalDeductions',
                'netPay',
            [    
                'label' => 'Action',    
                'content' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    if ($model->netPay != null) {
                        return Html::a('View Payslip', ['view' , 'id' => $model->payslipID], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
                    }else{
                        return Html::a('Create Payslip', ['create-new', 'id' => $model->user_id], ['class' => 'btn btn-warning']);
                    }
                }
            ]
        ],
    ]); 
?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

**Script**:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#period option:last-child").attr('selected', 'selected');

    $("#period").change( function()
    {
        var period = $('#period').val();

        if(period != 0){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?r=payslip/periods',
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'GET',
                data: {id: period},
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $.pjax.reload({container:'#employee'});
                    //alert(data.start);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('An error occured!');
                    alert('Error in ajax request');
                }
            });
        }
    }
    );
})
</script>
```

My question is, how do I preserve/maintain the style of the check boxes? And why does it change in style? And why are the styled check boxes not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes are changed with javascript to look like that.
You have 2 problems:
1) your "check all" function works just fine, you just need to refresh the status of the checkboxes afterwards. It works like this: when you click on the div that replaces the checkbox then the checkbox gets changed under it. Your problem is that you check it with the scripts so you need to trigger the div that sits on top of it to change too.
2) because you use pjax your page DOM gets changed. However because you probably change the checkboxes on "onload" of the page the new checkboxes remain unstyled. You need to run the function that changes them again after the pjax call.